# Is there a way to condense my Javascript code to make it more concise?

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a basic site that takes the input from a dropdown and also a text input and provides a result based on this. I'm fairly new to coding and am just making these as personal projects to learn from, but I feel like there must be a way to make this code more condensed? If anyone has any input to help me improve it'd be greatly appreciated!

Also I would like to know how to make it so the javascript will accept both Portsmouth and portsmouth not uppercase for example as currently it only accepts it if it's typed exactly as it is in the code.

Thanks :)

```
function chinesePortsmouth() {
    var chineseFood = ['The Taste Of China', 'Noble House', 'Tin Tin'];
    var chineseFood = chineseFood[Math.floor(Math.random() * chineseFood.length)];
    document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = chineseFood;
}

function chineseBrighton() {
    var chineseFood = ['China Garden', 'The Lucky Star', 'Good Friends'];
    var chineseFood = chineseFood[Math.floor(Math.random() * chineseFood.length)];
    document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = chineseFood;
}

function italianPortsmouth() {
    var italianFood = ['Bella Calabria', 'Sopranos', 'O Sole Mio Two'];
    var italianFood = italianFood[Math.floor(Math.random() * italianFood.length)];
    document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = italianFood;
}

function italianBrighton() {
    var italianFood = ['Al Duomo', 'Polpo Brighton', 'Si Signore'];
    var italianFood = italianFood[Math.floor(Math.random() * italianFood.length)];
    document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = italianFood;
}

function indianPortsmouth() {
    var indianFood = ['The Akash', 'Blue Cobra', 'Spice Merchants'];
    var indianFood = indianFood[Math.floor(Math.random() * indianFood.length)];
    document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = indianFood;
}

function indianBrighton() {
    var indianFood = ['Curry Leaf Cafe', 'Indian Summer', 'The Chilli Pickle'];
    var indianFood = indianFood[Math.floor(Math.random() * indianFood.length)];
    document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = indianFood;
}

function mexicanPortsmouth() {
    var mexicanFood = ['Chiquito', 'Bonitas', 'Las Iguanas'];
    var mexicanFood = mexicanFood[Math.floor(Math.random() * mexicanFood.length)];
    document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = mexicanFood;
}

function mexicanBrighton() {
    var mexicanFood = ['Dos Sombreros', 'Wahaca Brighton', 'Carlito Burrito'];
    var mexicanFood = mexicanFood[Math.floor(Math.random() * mexicanFood.length)];
    document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = mexicanFood;
}

function restChoice() {
    var e = document.getElementById("restaurants");
    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("search").value;
    if (result == "Chinese" && inputVal == "Portsmouth") {
        chinesePortsmouth();
    } else if (result == "Chinese" && inputVal == "Brighton") {
        chineseBrighton();
    } else if (result == "Italian" && inputVal == "Portsmouth") {
        italianPortsmouth();
    } else if (result == "Italian" && inputVal == "Brighton") {
        italianBrighton();
    } else if (result == "Indian" && inputVal == "Portsmouth") {
        indianPortsmouth();
    } else if (result == "Indian" && inputVal == "Brighton") {
        indianBrighton();
    } else if (result == "Mexican" && inputVal == "Portsmouth") {
        mexicanPortsmouth();
    } else if (result == "Mexican" && inputVal == "Brighton") {
        mexicanBrighton();
    }
}

  <button onclick="restChoice()" id="button">Button</button>
    <select id="restaurants">
        <option value = "1" id="chi">Chinese</option>
        <option value = "2" id="ita">Italian</option>
        <option value = "3" id="ind">Indian</option>
        <option value = "4" id="mex">Mexican</option>
      </select>

    <input type="text" id="search">

    <div id="restDisplay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to check for code on which you are always repeating yourself. Remember the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. Also make functions do what they are specifically tasked to do, this will help you pinpoint errors/bugs in the future. You can try to use Objects to group logic and assign methods to it. In this case, I use an object to group the restaurant food choices in arrays. Then created a function to pick a food based on the chosen restaurant.

```
const restaurants = {
  chinesePortsmouth: ['The Taste Of China', 'Noble House', 'Tin Tin'],
  chineseBrighton: ['China Garden', 'The Lucky Star', 'Good Friends'],
  italianFood: ['Bella Calabria', 'Sopranos', 'O Sole Mio Two'],
  italianBrighton: ['Al Duomo', 'Polpo Brighton', 'Si Signore'],
  indianPortsmouth: ['The Akash', 'Blue Cobra', 'Spice Merchants'],
  indianBrighton: ['Curry Leaf Cafe', 'Indian Summer', 'The Chilli Pickle'],
  mexicanPortsmouth: ['Chiquito', 'Bonitas', 'Las Iguanas'],
  mexicanBrighton: ['Dos Sombreros', 'Wahaca Brighton', 'Carlito Burrito']
};

function pickFood (foodChoices) {
  return foodChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * foodChoices.length)];
}

function restChoice() {
  var e = document.getElementById('restaurants');
  var inputVal = document.getElementById('search').value.toLowerCase();
  var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  let name = null;
  
  if (result == 'Chinese' && inputVal == 'porstmouth') {
    name = 'chinesePortsmouth';
  } else if (result == 'Chinese' && inputVal == 'Brighton') {
    name = 'chineseBrighton';
  } else if (result == 'Italian' && inputVal == 'porstmouth') {
    name = 'italianPortsmouth';
  } else if (result == 'Italian' && inputVal == 'Brighton') {
    name = 'italianBrighton';
  } else if (result == 'Indian' && inputVal == 'porstmouth') {
    name = 'indianPortsmouth';
  } else if (result == 'Indian' && inputVal == 'Brighton') {
    name = 'indianBrighton';
  } else if (result == 'Mexican' && inputVal == 'porstmouth') {
    name = 'mexicanPortsmouth';
  } else if (result == 'Mexican' && inputVal == 'Brighton') {
    name = 'mexicanBrighton';
  }

  // Render food choice
  document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = pickFood(restaurants[name]);
}
```

> For accepting Portsmouth and portsmouth, just check for the spelling regardless of it's stylecase. In this case, lowercase the entered value first and just compare it to "portsmouth".

```
// Can be Portsmouth,portsmouth,PORTSMOUTH,pOrtSmouth
var inputVal = document.getElementById('search').value;

if (inputVal.toLowerCase() === 'portsmouth) {
  // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to refactor, a good tip is to always think of what makes each function unique. In this case, the only difference between your functions is the array. Given this, you can create a function that takes in an array, since it's the only unknown.

```
function setRestDisplay(foodItems) {
    var item = foodItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * foodItems.length)];
    document.getElementById("restDisplay").innerHTML = foodItems;
}
```

Try and figure out `restChoice` on your own and let me know if you're still stuck :)